# dynamically creating tabs and content in angularjs using data from database

Tags: angularjs, tabs

after a couple of months with angularjs, I have come to appreciate the extra effort required to grasp it. So I decided to get a bit adventurous. The follwing code works except that the data is displayed at the wrong places

```
 <tabs>
<div ng-repeat="dept in dpt.depts">
    <pane title={{dept.DepartmentName}}>
          <div class="panel panel-default" >
                <div class="panel-heading" >
                    <h6>
                        Programmes
                    </h6>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" >
                    <ul class="list-group" >
                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="prog in dept.Programmes|filter: {DepartmentID:dept.DepartmentID}">
                            {{prog.ProgramName}} 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
   </pane>
</div>
```

The department names appear corectly as the panel titles but the programmes being run in the various departments appear on all tabs. Idea is to restrict programmes in each department to the relevant tab.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Really not clear what the problem is. Are you saying layout is wrong? or filter isn't working?

Comment: @charlietfl, Yeah pretty much so. I end up having situation like this: Let say I have Information Science department, Engineering department and so on and so forth. Now, they all have their specific programmes they run. Now what I have is each tab ends up displaying all the programmes.

Comment: Hard to know why filter isn't working without a data sample.

Comment: Alternative is do the filtering in controller and nest as children of each department

Comment: @charlietfl I mean the layout. the filtering works out fine. Both departments and programmes are dynamically loaded from the database

Comment: You sure the markup is correct based on tabs directive?

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah it is

Comment: Create a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that reproduces problem

Comment: @charlietfl Okay give me a couple of minutes